# jquery with if structure

Tags: jquery, wordpress, conditional-statements

How can I use jquery to bring up one of two different divs based on if a user is logged in or not?

For my wordpress site I have a menu item that I need to prompt the user to first log in or register (via my fancybox iframe), and if already logged in to instead bring up another div (to access posts). Both these options are set up, I just don't know how to structure the code as an IF structure or some sort of conditional code. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use JQuery. Distinction between logged in users to visitors content must only be done on the **server side**. You don't want the server to send info addressed at logged users only, to visitors. That makes your login system highly penetrable - to say the least -  as the info is already on the client-side and he can access it easily (e.g. simply by turning JS off or viewing page source).

The basic structure using WP built-in function would be:

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
    //logged user info
<?php else: ?>
    //login form
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I put this in functions.php with jquery in script tags.

Answer (score 1):

Just vary the selector based on the condition:

```
var selector = loggedIn ? '#log-in' : '#view-posts';
$(selector).show();
```

Obviously you'll need to vary the selectors to actually match your page, as well as the `loggedIn` condition to match whatever your condition is.